# How to change the Header and Footer in Magento 2.2.0

Tags: magento2

I am new to Magneto 2. I want to change the default Header and Footer and place my custom Header and Footer instead. I am using Magento 2.2.0, Please help me.

Comment: what all did you try ?

Comment: gone through this link C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html and there is both header and footer, I made changes to them but nothing happend.